Could not find com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2
My steps are very simple.
react-native init exampleApp
npm install react-native-twilio-programmable-voice
react-native run-android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2.
Searched in the following locations:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/getkeepsafe/relinker/relinker/1.2.2/relinker-1.2.2.pom
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/getkeepsafe/relinker/relinker/1.2.2/relinker-1.2.2.pom
file:/D:/z/front/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/getkeepsafe/relinker/relinker/1.2.2/relinker-1.2.2.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/getkeepsafe/relinker/relinker/1.2.2/relinker-1.2.2.pom
https://www.jitpack.io/com/getkeepsafe/relinker/relinker/1.2.2/relinker-1.2.2.pom
Required by:
project :app > project :react-native-twilio-programmable-voice > com.twilio:voice-android:4.5.0


